# HTML::HTMLDoc installation issue on Strawberry Perl

Tags: perl, cpan, strawberry-perl

I am trying to build [`HTML::HTMLDoc`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::HTMLDoc) on Strawberry Perl (32 bit) on XP. I consistently face the following problem even after re-installing Strawberry. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
cpan> install HTML::HTMLDoc
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/modules/03modlist.data.gz
Creating database file ...
Done!
Running install for module 'HTML::HTMLDoc'
Running make for M/MF/MFRANKL/HTML-HTMLDoc-0.10.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/id/M/MF/MFRANKL/HTML-HTMLDoc-0.10.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/id/M/MF/MFRANKL/CHECKSUMS
Checksum for C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\authors\id\M\MF\MFRANKL\HTML-HTMLDoc-0.10.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache C:\strawberry\cpan\build for sizes
DONE

  CPAN.pm: Building M/MF/MFRANKL/HTML-HTMLDoc-0.10.tar.gz

Unparsable version '' for prerequisite IPC::Open3 at Makefile.PL line 4.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for HTML::HTMLDoc
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
cp lib/HTML/HTMLDoc.pm blib\lib\HTML\HTMLDoc.pm
cp lib/HTML/HTMLDoc/PDF.pm blib\lib\HTML\HTMLDoc\PDF.pm
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe "-Iblib\arch" "-Iblib\lib" test_htmldoc.PL test_htmldoc
'htmldoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
htmldoc not found. please install first
dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'test_htmldoc'
  MFRANKL/HTML-HTMLDoc-0.10.tar.gz
  C:\strawberry\c\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'HTML::HTMLDoc'.
Failed during this command:
 MFRANKL/HTML-HTMLDoc-0.10.tar.gz             : make NO
```

Comment: Do you have htmldoc installed and set up in your path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HTML::HTMLDoc](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::HTMLDoc) is just a wrapper around the [htmldoc](http://www.msweet.org/projects.php?Z1) program. When your error says

> 'htmldoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file. htmldoc not found. please install
>   first

I suspect it's telling you that you need to install htmldoc before installing HTML::HTMLDoc.

Comment: you are right - htmldoc was not installed but not properly. That turned out to be the real issue.